# Color or highlight each duplicate in a column with different color with pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, colors, duplicates, highlight

I would like to `highlight` duplicates in a column so its easier to the eye to spot them out. Not really sure how I should do this as the numbers might change now and then based on import data.

I manage to `highlight` the `duplicates` with this code but its terrible colors and it seems impossible to change color-palette(?)

> `colors = dict(zip(unique_fraud['IMSI'].unique(),`
> (f'background-color: {c}' for c in plt.colors.cnames.values())))
> unique_fraud.style.applymap(colors.get, subset=['IMSI'])

My data looks like this at the moment
[Picture of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phrci.png)

Could anyone help me with a code that works or if its possible to change palette with my current code? thanks

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419661/pandas-style-applymap-highlight-duplicates-with-lambda-function

Comment: Yeah I checked that one out! It works but it highlights the entire row and with the same color. Ideally for me would be as my picture but better coloring, do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = dict(zip(unique_fraud['IMSI'].unique(), (f'background-color: {c}' for c in plt.colors.cnames.values()))) unique_fraud.style.applymap(colors.get, subset=['IMSI'])
```

solution is to delete plt.colors.cnames.values() and add a custom_color variable such as this
``custom_color = ["#12345", "#CC4AAD", "other colorcodes"]